# How can I update npz file in python?

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5

I have a large data-set that I want save them in a npz file. But because the size of file is big for memory I cant save them in npz file.
Now i want insert data in iterations into npz file.
How can I do this?
Are HDF5 is better for this?

Answer (score 0):

accepted

`locals().update(npzfile)`
a   # and/or b

In the Ipython session, `locals()` is a large dictionary with variables the you've defined, the input history lines, and various outputs. Update adds the dictionary values of npzfile to that larger one.

By the way, you can also load and save MATLAB .mat files. Use scipy.io.loadmat and savemat. It handles v4 (Level 1.0), v6 and v7 to 7.2 files. But you have same issue - the result is a dictionary.

Octave has an expression form of the load command, that loads the data into a structure

`S = load ("file", "options", "v1", "v2", ...)`